# Can i import the same css from "additional css" from parent theme to child theme?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently developing a site using oceanwpxelementor, and I am having this problem with parent to child theme conversion. I have made the mistake by not creating a child theme from the beginning, and now I have created layers of css under the additional css function. Today, I created the child theme, and tried pasting all the additional css to the child theme; however, the side completely broke. Is there anything I need to add to make the additional css functions work  the same for the child theme as they do for the parent?

Thank you,

Comment: All the default styles of parent will be available in child theme. Since you have added the additional styles to child theme everything should work fine. Is the additional css added via external style sheet?

Comment: www.ritasaraci.com/shop    - this is the site!

Comment: i cannot see broken css in the site url you have given

Comment: Ok. Now i see that

Comment: @melvin I have no idea why its breaking the site this way...

Comment: There are errors in console. Also please turn on debug mode and check if there are errors on your debug log.

Comment: @melvin Notice: Undefined index: wpforms in /home/ritasara/public_html/wp-content/plugins/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite/includes/class-eae-elements.php on line 127

This is the error that is appearing

Comment: There is some error with the plugin. Remeber any changes you made to php ?

Comment: Try to deactivate the plugin and check if the issue is fixed for now.